# Detecting browser width with media query using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to implement a precise way of figuring out the user's browser width based on a media query. For example, I have an element div called `#check_screen` initially it'll be displayed as a block element. If the browser width is < 420px, then `#check_screen` will have a `display: none` property. This is what I have tried so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id='check_screen'></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#check_screen{
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px){
    #check_screen{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

//Function to the css rule
function checkSize(){
    if ($("#check_screen").css("display") == "none" ){
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

For some reason, it is not working correctly. When I resize the screen to < 420px, the message is not displayed to the console. I have also tried using the :visible jQuery selector, but that does not work either. I am using Chrome as my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error:
`$(window).resize(checkSize);` should be

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    checkSize();
});
```

That correction worked for me with no other changes.

Comment: Ahh I see! My resize function was outside the document.ready function. Thank you!

Comment: You could also just use `if ($(window).width() < 420) {console.log("Hello")};` inside the `$(window).resize( function() { ` so JS is handling the screen size check instead of relying on CSS media-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assign unvisible div and set its color to black.

If resized, change its color to green.

Javascript would be like

```
var check = $("element").css("background-color");

if(check == "black" {
}

else if...
```

Comment: Have you included jquery, and then this script? Did you put this in onLoad? Post your code on the fiddle.